# kernel panic- not syncing: attempted to kill init!

Tags: 10.04

I am not very technical.
My system has frozen 3 times in March--- this is what was on screen...

```
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS Admin.sybalsky.com tty1
admin.sybalsky.com login: [683454.747106]
kernel panic- not syncing: attempted to kill init!
```

I know the system is running:

> Linux admin.sybalsky.com 2.6.32-40-generic-pae #87-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 5 21:44:34 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
>   Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Can you tell me what this all means and why it is happening and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed for some reason (and whether this is true or not, I'm not sure) that Linux is very sensitive to failing hardware. I have seen this on my home office computer a couple of times. Your best bet is to start running hardware diagnostics.

For that I would recommend Ultimate Boot CD. In your case, I would start with running a Memtest (at least for an hour, overnight if possible), followed by a hard drive test (which test will depend on the brand of your hard drive). Out of those two, I would bet a lot of money that something would show up defective - and my money would be on memory.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it happens for some kind of filesystem corruption or partition damage.
for example recently, when i try to run `*.vdi` file,that installed in another machine, i see this line when i start that virtual.
Possibly even Hard Drive failure?
try following guide, 
[it worked for me, virtual OS:`centos 5.5`] :
1.When in Rescue mode (from the CD) - Choose Continue.
2.Before running 'chroot /mnt/sysimage'
Run:

```
# df -h
# fdisk -l
```